# Normality of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, there is an exercise of normality of a metric space $X$. It states that every closed set $A\subset X$ is $Z(f)$ for some continuous real $f$ on $X$. Setting $V=f^{-1}([0,1/2))$, then $V$ is open. The solution says that $V$ is open since it is an inverse image of an open set containing $0$. In fact, $[0,1/2)$ is not open. I  need a more specific explanation here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $f(x) \ge 0$, you can see that $f^{-1}([0,\alpha)) = f^{-1}((-1,\alpha))$. Since $(-1,\alpha)$ is open, it follows that $V$ would be open too.

Answer (score 2):

The codomain of $f$ is the space $[0,1]$, with the topology that it inherits from $\Bbb R$; in that topology $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ **is** an open set. E.g., it’s the intersection with $[0,1]$ of the open set $\left(-1,\frac12\right)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full text of the problem:

[image]

Since the range of $f$ lies in $[0,1]$, for any $a<0$ we have
$$V=f^{-1}([0,\tfrac{1}{2}))=f^{-1}((a,\tfrac{1}{2}))$$
and thus $V$ is an open set.