# Rudin Ex. 4.22. Every closed set $A \subset X$ is $Z(f)$ for some continuous real $f$ on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused about the English of this sentence. (Since I am self-studying, I may be unfamiliar with some conventions). But what does this mean by ``Every closed set $A\subset X$ is $Z(f)$''? What in particular is $Z(f)$? I found a similar thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997759/normality-of-a-metric-space), but my confusion is not quite answered.

[image]

Comment: I believe that $Z(f)$ indicates the set of all elements $p$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(p)=0.$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! That makes sense. Also, I found that "for some f" is just the f defined above, but not some other f that satisfies the condition of A=Z(f). I believe deleting the sentence makes the problem more clear.

Comment: You're welcome! That said, the sentence you mention can't be deleted, as it is a direct reference to an earlier problem, showing that every closed set in $X$ is the zero set of some function whose domain is $X.$ That said, I disagree with Rudin's use of "*a* converse" in this case, as it is only an example. Rather, ***the*** converse would be to show that, given any continuous function $f:X\to\Bbb R,$ the zero set of $f$ is closed in $X.$

Comment: Hi, thank you. I still believe this sentence should at least be replaced by: Every closed set $A\subset X$ is the zero set of the function $f(p)=\frac{\rho_A(p)}{\rho_A(p)+\rho_B(p)}$ for some nonempty closed set B which is disjoint with A. When it says *some function,* I was constructing my own like $f(p)=\rho_A(p)$ which satisfies the condition $Z(f)=A$ but I couldn't continue with the exercise.

Comment: I completely understand your confusion! The problem was not qualified well, at all.

Comment: Rudin can be rather terse at times.

Comment: You have to go back and read exercise 4.3 to discover that $Z(f)$ is defined as the set of all $p \in X$ at which $f(p) = 0$.